# Sending multiple mails to different recipients from Django Backend

Tags: django, websocket, redis, celery, message-queue

I will do my best to explain the system clearly. Please read through the entire description, and if you have any questions, feel free to ask in the comments.

The system I am building allows registered users to send invitations to multiple recipients with a single click of the submit button. In the invitation form, users can enter multiple recipients as a comma-separated string. When they click the submit button, they will immediately receive a notification indicating that the invitations were sent successfully. The backend will then communicate with the user through web sockets to update the status of each recipient's invitation from 'pending' to 'delivered.' (I have learned that a message queue or service worker is required in the backend to complete the email sending task asynchronously.)

When the user submits the request, my view will create an invitation instance for each comma-separated recipient and call a function for the email sending task. Please take a look at my code for a better understanding.

My views.py file:

```
class InvitationCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Invitation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvitationSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        title = request.data.get('title')
        message = request.data.get('message')
        recipients = request.data.get('recipients').split(',')

        invitation_ids = []

        for recipient in recipients:
            recipient = recipient.strip()
            invitation = Invitation.objects.create(
                sender = request.user,
                recipients = recipient,
                title = title,
                status = 'pending'
            )
            print("================executed================")
            #This is for debugging. the print is getting executed once even if there are multiple recipients
            invitation_ids.append(invitation.id)

            send_invitation_email.delay(invitation.id, recipient, title, message)
        
        return Response({'invitations_ids': invitation_ids}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

My view is only creating an invitation instance for only first recipient from the recipients string. and then it fails and throws an error:

```
OperationalError at /api/v1/invitations/invitation/
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I used Celery for asynchronous email sending, but it doesn't seem to be working. Emails are not being sent to the intended recipients.

tasks.py file:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from celery import shared_task

from .models import Invitation


@shared_task
def send_invitation_email(invitation_id, recipients, title, message):
    invitation = Invitation.objects.get(id=invitation_id)
    recipients_list = recipients.split(',')

    try:
        for recipient in recipients_list:
            send_mail(
                # f'Invitation from {invitation.sender.name}',
                title,
                message,
                invitation.sender.email,
                [recipient.strip()],
                fail_silently=False
            )
        invitation.status = 'delivered'
    except Exception as e:
        invitation.status = 'failed'
    
    invitation.save()
```

For the mail backend I configured like this:

```
MAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = env.str('EMAIL_HOST', '')
EMAIL_PORT = env.str('EMAIL_PORT', '')
EMAIL_HOST_USER =  env.str('EMAIL_HOST_USER', '')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env.str('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD', '')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = env.bool('EMAIL_USE_TLS', False)
```

While conducting research on best practices for implementing asynchronous tasks in my project, I came across Redis and Celery as recommended tools. Although I initially had some uncertainty about their use, I have since configured my Celery settings to incorporate Redis

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

I am seeking guidance on how to achieve my objective. While I can easily send a success notification to the user in the frontend, I am having difficulty getting the asynchronous task to work properly in the backend.
If you could also provide some guidance on how to set up websockets for communication between the frontend and backend to update the status of invitations from 'pending' to 'delivered', it would be greatly appreciated.

The entire error:

```
OperationalError at /api/v1/invitations/invitation/
[Errno 111] Connection refused

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/invitations/invitation/
Django Version: 4.2
Python Executable: /home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path: ['/home/imtiapy/Desktop/allProjects/invitePeople/server', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time: Mon, 01 May 2023 11:44:24 +0000
Installed Applications:



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 30, in __call__
    return self.__value__

During handling of the above exception ('ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'), another exception occurred:
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 446, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 433, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 312, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 877, in _connection_factory
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 812, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 201, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 129, in connect
    self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 184, in _connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)

The above exception ([Errno 111] Connection refused) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/imtiapy/Desktop/allProjects/invitePeople/server/invitations/api/views.py", line 31, in create
    send_invitation_email.delay(invitation.id, recipient, title, message)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 425, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 575, in apply_async
    return app.send_task(
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 788, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 510, in send_task_message
    ret = producer.publish(
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 177, in publish
    return _publish(
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 523, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 186, in _publish
    channel = self.channel
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 209, in _get_channel
    channel = self._channel = channel()
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 32, in __call__
    value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 225, in <lambda>
    channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 895, in default_channel
    self._ensure_connection(**conn_opts)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 433, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 450, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    raise ConnectionError(str(exc)) from exc

Exception Type: OperationalError at /api/v1/invitations/invitation/
Exception Value: [Errno 111] Connection refused
Raised during: invitations.api.views.InvitationCreateView
Request information:
USER: 4-Imtiaz Ahmed

GET: No GET data

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES: No cookie data

META:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = '*,'
COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
CONTENT_LENGTH = '170'
CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/json'
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = 'http://localhost:3000'
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = 'http://localhost:3000,http://localhost:8000'
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
DEBUG = '1'
DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
DISPLAY = ':0'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'config.settings'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'ahmedimtiaz561@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = 'True'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = 'CGI/1.1'
GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = '6980'
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
HOME = '/home/imtiapy'
HTTP_ACCEPT = 'application/json'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = 'gzip, deflate, br'
HTTP_AUTHORIZATION = 'JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjg0MTY2NzcyLCJpYXQiOjE2ODI4NDczNzQsImp0aSI6IjJjMTZjODBjNjE4ZTQwYTFiMjIxYTIzOWI1ZjU1MTliIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6NH0.N4P6Uu2JaE0kdjCz-G0vm67m1KWXJo94o6EmptrPl4s'
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL = 'no-cache'
HTTP_CONNECTION = 'keep-alive'
HTTP_HOST = '127.0.0.1:8000'
HTTP_POSTMAN_TOKEN = '********************'
HTTP_USER_AGENT = 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.4'
IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
INVOCATION_ID = 'da9851ac375c41c89fa9f349ea6f365c'
JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:57493'
LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
LC_ADDRESS = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LC_MEASUREMENT = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LC_MONETARY = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LC_NAME = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LC_NUMERIC = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LC_PAPER = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LC_TELEPHONE = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LC_TIME = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
LOGNAME = 'imtiapy'
LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
MANAGERPID = '2274'
MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path'
NVM_BIN = '/home/imtiapy/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin'
NVM_CD_FLAGS = ''
NVM_DIR = '/home/imtiapy/.nvm'
NVM_INC = '/home/imtiapy/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/include/node'
OLDPWD = '/home/imtiapy/Desktop/allProjects/invitePeople'
PAPERSIZE = 'a4'
PATH = '/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/bin:/home/imtiapy/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin:/home/imtiapy/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
PATH_INFO = '/api/v1/invitations/invitation/'
PIPENV_ACTIVE = '1'
PIP_PYTHON_PATH = '/usr/bin/python3'
PS1 = '(server-VF5IsesZ) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ '
PWD = '/home/imtiapy/Desktop/allProjects/invitePeople/server'
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE = '1'
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = '1'
QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
QUERY_STRING = ''
REMOTE_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_HOST = ''
REQUEST_METHOD = 'POST'
RUN_MAIN = 'true'
SCRIPT_NAME = ''
SECRET_KEY = '********************'
SERVER_NAME = 'localhost'
SERVER_PORT = '8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE = 'WSGIServer/0.2'
SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/imtiazpy:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2504,unix/imtiazpy:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2504'
SHELL = '/bin/bash'
SHLVL = '2'
SSH_AGENT_PID = '2465'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
TERM = 'xterm-256color'
TERMINATOR_DBUS_NAME = 'net.tenshu.Terminator21a9d5db22c73a993ff0b42f64b396873'
TERMINATOR_DBUS_PATH = '/net/tenshu/Terminator2'
TERMINATOR_UUID = 'urn:uuid:9580f5d3-1aed-4081-a3aa-302c4b3ba42e'
TZ = 'UTC'
USER = 'imtiapy'
USERNAME = 'imtiapy'
VIRTUAL_ENV = '/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ'
VTE_VERSION = '6003'
WINDOWPATH = '2'
XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
_ = '/home/imtiapy/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-VF5IsesZ/bin/python'
wsgi.errors = <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper = <class 'wsgiref.util.FileWrapper'>
wsgi.input = <django.core.handlers.wsgi.LimitedStream object at 0x7fbdeacec460>
wsgi.multiprocess = False
wsgi.multithread = True
wsgi.run_once = False
wsgi.url_scheme = 'http'
wsgi.version = '(1, 0)'

Settings:
Using settings module config.settings
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {}
ADMINS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
APPEND_SLASH = True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = '********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
BASE_DIR = PosixPath('/home/imtiapy/Desktop/allProjects/invitePeople/server')
CACHES = {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = '********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 600
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:8000']
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = 31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_MASKED = False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = []
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': PosixPath('/home/imtiapy/Desktop/allProjects/invitePeople/server/db.sqlite3'), 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS': False, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '********************', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'MIGRATE': True, 'MIRROR': None, 'NAME': None}}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = []
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 1000
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FILES = 100
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M']
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y', '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y', '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG = True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER = 'django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER = 'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE = ''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE = ''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = []
DJOSER = {'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email', 'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': '********************', 'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True, 'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': '********************', 'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True, 'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': '********************', 'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': '********************', 'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}', 'ACTIVATION_URL': 'api/v1/users/activate/{uid}/{token}', 'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True, 'SERIALIZERS': {'user_create': 'users.api.serializers.UserSerializer', 'user': 'users.api.serializers.UserSerializer', 'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer'}}
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'ahmedimtiaz561@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE = None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE = '********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler', 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 420
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 0
FIXTURE_DIRS = []
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = None
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'users', 'invitations', 'rest_framework', 'corsheaders', 'djoser']
INTERNAL_IPS = []

LANGUAGES_BIDI = ['he', 'ar', 'ar-dz', 'ckb', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SECURE = False
LOCALE_PATHS = []
LOCAL_APPS = ['users', 'invitations']
LOGGING = {}
LOGGING_CONFIG = 'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = None
MAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
MANAGERS = []
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/imtiapy/Desktop/allProjects/invitePeople/server/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE = ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES = {}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING = 0
PASSWORD_HASHERS = '********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT = '********************'
PREPEND_WWW = False
REST_FRAMEWORK = {'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',), 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication', 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication')}
ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'
SECRET_KEY = '********************'
SECRET_KEY_FALLBACKS = '********************'
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = 'same-origin'
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = []
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = 'same-origin'
SECURE_SSL_HOST = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SERVER_EMAIL = 'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = 'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_FILE_PATH = None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE = 'config.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND = 'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = []
SIMPLE_JWT = {'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',), 'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': '********************', 'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': '********************'}
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder', 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = None
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STORAGES = {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'}, 'staticfiles': {'BACKEND': 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'}}
TEMPLATES = [{'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', 'DIRS': [], 'APP_DIRS': True, 'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug', 'django.template.context_processors.request', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS = []
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = ['rest_framework', 'corsheaders', 'djoser']
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ','
TIME_FORMAT = 'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_DEPRECATED_PYTZ = False
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False
USE_TZ = True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT = False
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'
```

Comment: please post complete error trace. Is redis and a celery worker running in the  background?

Comment: I'm new to using Redis and Celery, and I've just installed the two libraries and integrated the settings into my settings.py file. The full error traceback has been included, and I would greatly appreciate any assistance. @Razenstein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to follow one of the tutorials that you can find on google for "django redis celery" e.g. https://testdriven.io/courses/django-celery/getting-started/  (I do not know a simple link here on stackoverflow)

You need to have 4 things:

1. install redis and run it (that is the message queue)
2. install celery in your virt.env
3. have celery add to your django app to create tasks (@shared_task) sent to redis by function.delay(...)

   -> start in console with `python manage.py runserver`
4. have a celery worker running that reads form redis and executes shared tasks 
   -> start in another console with `celery -A django_celery_sample worker`

If I am right, you have until now only #2 and #3.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about my position #2 and #3. I am really missing out on #1. 
Thanks for the tutorial link.